# Using Beego with Angular, e.g redefine "{{}}" interpolation?

Tags: angularjs, beego

I am investigating the use of Beego and Angular. One issue is that they both use curly braces for variable substitution. I know that Revel allows redefinition of the interpolation characters in order to avoid conflicts. Does Beego offer a similar feature?

TIA,

Eric G.

Comment: Does Go and Beego output html to the browser, or is it something that runs in the browser. If it's outputting html to the browser, there is no conflict.

Comment: Unless, i guess, if you were using beego inside your angular templates, but that doesn't make sense to me. Not sure why you would do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can [change Beego's interpolation tags](http://beego.me/docs/mvc/view/view.md#template-tags) by adding the following option to your configuration:

```
beego.TemplateLeft = "<<<"
beego.TemplateRight = ">>>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many Beego codes already finished, you could use ngBind. And also, I prefer to use ngBind, because it generates less "trash" on code :-)

Comment: Please mark it as an aswer if it, or another answer, had solved your problem.